# HTML/CSS/JS translation - is this grid in my project? If not - do I need one to code this project?

Tags: frontend, photoshop, psd

I need to translate PSD file into HTML/CSS/JS...

Here is this project:

https://s15.postimg.org/s421pj5mj/PSD.jpg

https://s24.postimg.org/8xq87z3v9/PSD_2.jpg

QUESTION What are those 1.vertical and 2.horizontal sky-blue lines and how are they supposed to help me as for somebody who translates this PSD into HTML/CSS/JS ? Don't they seem a bit chaotic?

Answer (score 0):

Despite being blue in your example, these are called "Redlines". The lines are meant to help you see the alignment, sizing, and spacing of elements.

For example, there is one center line down the very middle. You can use that to see that the "Creative Digital Solutons" text is centered, as is the the "Personal Services" text, "Responsive web" section, and "Latest project" section.

You can also see that at the very bottom of the second image, certain pieces of text in each column should line up with certain pieces in other columns.

Usually you will find a particular element or group of elements like this:

[image]

With the red lines I added you can see that the icons should all be the same width, and the left side of the icons should align with the left side of "Latest Posts".

Sometimes these redlines contain specific measurements (font: 14pt, margin: 10px, etc.), but this one doesn't, so you just have to use the lines to help you visualize

Yes it is chaotic, but that's how it goes sometimes

Comment: What about grid (there is no grid here). How do I make one if there is no grid provided ? Do I need grid to translate this project into html/css/js or can I do without grid ?

Comment: These lines are your grid. You can arbitrarily overlay a grid on top if you think that will help, but it is unnecessary. These blue lines should not be in your final output, they are just to help you. Rather than lining things up with some other grid, you line them up with the lines provided

Comment: I've seen quite a lot psd projects and in some there are those "redlines" and in other there are girds (like here: https://woocommerce.com/wp-content/themes/woo/images/storefront/feature-2.jpg)

I dont know what is the difference between redlines and grid as far as translating PSD to html/css/js is concerned....

Comment: As far as I grasp it know 1. "redlines"(help guides) and 2. grid ,  are not the same thing.

Comment: The grid gives you some discrete units. In the grid link you shared, it is saying "the screen is 24 units wide and the images are 5 units wide and have 1 unit between them".

The images in your original question don't have that information, but that's fine. You base the sizes and alignments off what you can see. Different but similar information.